# In Spark Sql, if we have when(A&B) and if A is evaluated as false, then will B will still be evaluated?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

In Spark Sql, if we have when(A&B) and if A is evaluated as false, then will B will still be evaluated ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, if A is false, then B won't be evaluated. To check that you can run the following queries:

```
SELECT true and assert_true(false) is null
SELECT false and assert_true(false) is null
```

Query #1 will fail, query #2 will not.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it will, as shown in the following example where the non-existent column is attempted to be evaluated, but I'm not 100% sure:

```
spark-sql> select false & none;
Error in query: cannot resolve '`none`' given input columns: []; line 1 pos 15;
'Project [unresolvedalias((false & 'none), None)]
+- OneRowRelation
```

Comment: Same issue with me also, the non existent column is getting evaluated. and this is the only reason I had to ask this question to get confirmation. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: A column existence is evaluated at query planning stage, while the final column value - at execution stage

Comment: Good point @falcon-le0, but I'm not sure how to determine if the column value is evaluated or not though...